# WPF Context Sensitive Help - Best Practice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a wpf application for context sensitive help using .chm files. I have created a a context sensitive help by pressing F1 after clicking a textbox or a button, thorugh xaml, AND NOT BY EVENT HANDLING. , but I need it for window also. I can have the window help as default in xaml when the window is loaded itself, which works now. But if i use text box help, then I cant switch back to window help since I have not included any events for that.

For this scenario, is using events the only possibility to include window help? what is the best practice? Is there a way to use window focus on xaml itself, or using event ends up as the best practice?

thanks a lot !!

Comment: Is Tooltip not enough with maybe a general help childwindow for the window invoked by your f1?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implement a F1 Help System? it's pretty straightforward...

Take a look at this example [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2007/07/26/a-context-sensitive-help-provider-in-wpf.aspx). This provides a HelpProvider class that gives you context sensitive help on any element that sets a HelpString. This should provide roughly what you need.

In your case, just make the chm file name your help name for each element you want a file sensitive to. And you could have something like so:

```
static private void Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    YourHelpSystem.ShowHelp(HelpProvider.GetHelpString(sender as FrameworkElement) + ".chm");
}
```

Comment: i already have this, and the help string is passed in the window tag, but my problem is after i click text box or button, then if i try to come back 2 window, it doesnt work. Probably something to do with focus cursor on window.. but I am not sure whether that is the best practice.. even if this can be a solution, I am not sure whether I should really have an event handler for this, or use something in  xaml

Comment: Have the mousedown event either set the tag again, or you could even just try giving the window focus listening to the mousedown event? Alternatively, you could just have the Application catch all F1 requests that aren't handled at a lower framework element (such as your textbox), and show your window's help file there.

Comment: The link is dead